# Enforcing types after mapping variable keys

Tags: typescript

I want to map an object and preserve types. I know how to do this with a single object, as such:

```
type MapTo<T, U> = {
  [P in keyof T]: U
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

export const mapObject = <ObjectType extends object, MapType>(
  value: ObjectType,
  map: (v: ValueOf<ObjectType>) => MapType,
): MapTo<ObjectType, MapType> => {
  const mappedValue = {} as MapTo<ObjectType, MapType>;

  // Can't use `Object.keys` because it returns string[]
  for (const i in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      mappedValue[i] = map(value[i]);
    }
  }

  return mappedValue;
};
```

`a` can have a varying number of keys, but the values are the same type. Then, if I do the following:

```
const a = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };
const b = mapObject(a, (i) => i * 2);
```

`b` still has the key completion (i.e., typing `b.` will autosuggest the keys of the object, `x` and `y`).

---

Now, say I have the following code (apologies for the length!):

```
type MapTo<T, U> = {
  [P in keyof T]: U;
}
type Map<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

export const mapObjectTo = <ObjectType extends object, MapType>(
  value: ObjectType,
  map: (v: ValueOf<ObjectType>) => MapType,
): MapTo<ObjectType, MapType> => {
  const mappedValue = {} as MapTo<ObjectType, MapType>;

  // Can't use `Object.keys` because it returns string[]
  for (const i in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      mappedValue[i] = map(value[i]);
    }
  }

  return mappedValue;
};

export const mapObject = <ObjectType extends object>(
  value: ObjectType,
  map: (v: ValueOf<ObjectType>) => ObjectType[Extract<keyof ObjectType, string>],
): Map<ObjectType> => {
  const mappedValue = {} as Map<ObjectType>;

  // Can't use `Object.keys` because it returns string[]
  for (const i in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      mappedValue[i] = map(value[i]);
    }
  }

  return mappedValue;
};

const groups = {
  a: {
    x: 1,
  },
  b: {
    y: 2
  },
};
const mapGroupedObject = <ObjectType extends object, ReturnType>(
  groupedObject: ObjectType,
  map: (i: ValueOf<ObjectType[Extract<keyof ObjectType, string>]>) => ReturnType
) => {
  const mapGroups = <T extends object>(item: T) => {
    return mapObjectTo(item, map);
  };
  const mappedGroups = mapObject(groups, mapGroups);

  return mappedGroups;
};

const mappedGroups = mapGroupedObject(groups, () => 2);
mappedGroups.a.x;
```

Essentially, `mapGroupedObject` should be made up of n keys, which are all objects. For each of those objects, I want to map the values with a callback, and preserve the autocompletion

Again, `mappedGroups` has autocompletion, so types seem to be resolving the structure, but the types don't seem to work here for `mapGroups` argument in `const mappedGroups = mapObject(groups, mapGroups);` in `mapGroupedItems`. Also, I can't use a callback with a parameter for mapping because the types are unhappy when I do so

In fact, most of the types I've inferred from the previous functions `mapObject` and `mapObjectTo`. I'm really not sure what the hell `ObjectType[Extract<keyof ObjectType, string>]` really means, it was presented by static code analysis in VSCode.

What do I need to do to satisfy the type compiler? Also, is there a way to generalise `mapObject` and `mapObjectTo` into a single function, if there's only one type in the generic?

---

As per request to the comment, for the `groups` object in the second code block:

```
const groups = {
  a: {
    x: 1,
  },
  b: {
    y: 2
  },
};;

const mappedGroups = mapGroupedObject(groups, (item) => item * 2);
/* Outputs:
{
  a: {
    x: 2,
  },
  b: {
    y: 4
  },
}

And very importantly, preserves the structure in the type - 
that is: 
- typing `mappedGroups.` should suggest `mappedGroups.a` and `mappedGroups.b`, 
- typing `mappedGroups.a.` should suggest `mappedGroups.a.x`
*/
```

Comment: I think this question would be easier to understand if you showed the expected output/return type of running `groups` through `mapGroupedObject` function

Comment: @spender Question updated!

Comment: Not sure I get it, but [maybe I do?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gJxAVwA4RgXhgbwFAwwCGAXLgYTAB5kCMANBQL6OEBGZ+lMAnmQEzNGTANx48UHqgCmMAOJI0AFSmzsAJWmgEAEwA80BAEswcejE3b9hk2ZjIwAazAgA7mAB8HsRNUwAakQANgDyAGZ6CijoMNJUUNJgOhhRyqoeWBSpMXEJSRiWILoGUMam5oXFNuUwJmHSCAFeMAD8ATBkYNIAbg0+kjIwALJEqJpQkYo58YnJ8lMqMhXSUBmYFDgwANoA0nK1YDCO0jwgYfPREAC6nNt7-gdHJ2cXaBC7clc3FiswTH8wABkuCY4jwYQcwCgRnAMAAtqNJpdYjN8q9UItpMtVgAKOBkbIQcxwsg47pkQKhCKEjwASiwGXGtLIIzGKyRb2xGS4MCgAAskK4YABRBBIBA4gBELlgRjhqCC0jhiQSOkltLwoLBoEgsAS0Cw8NGeKmRJg3QZMAABnzpEEgiAACQ4bpMK0aoA)

Comment: I'll provide an implementation if you tell me I'm barking up the right tree with the types.

Comment: It looks perfect on the types!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define a nested record type:

```js
type GroupType = Record<string, Record<string, unknown>>;
```

a type to `infer` the unknown types of the "leaf" values from a `GroupType`:

```js
type ValOf<Groups extends GroupType> =
  Groups extends Record<string, Record<string, infer V>> ? V : never;
```

and a type to map these "leaf" values to a different type:

```js
type MapRet<Groups extends GroupType, Ret> =
  { [KG in keyof Groups]: { [KGV in keyof Groups[KG]]: Ret } } & {}
```

(here we use `& {}` to expand the type in intellisense... it can be omitted if that doesn't bother you)

Now we can define a function to implement your needs:

```js
function map<G extends GroupType, Ret>(g: G, m: (v: ValOf<G>) => Ret): 
  MapRet<G, Ret> {
   return Object.fromEntries(
     Object.entries(g).map(
       ([k, v]) => [
         k,
         Object.fromEntries(
           Object.entries(v).map(([ki, vi]) => [ki, m(vi as ValOf<G>)])
         )
       ])
   ) as MapRet<G, Ret>
}
```

and call it:

```js
const groups = {
  a: {
    x: 1,
  },
  b: {
    y: 2
  },
};
const test = map(groups, v => `hello${v}`);
/*
typeof test:
{
    a: {
        x: string;
    };
    b: {
        y: string;
    };
}
*/
console.log(test);
```

for output of

```json
{
  "a": {
    "x": "hello1"
  },
  "b": {
    "y": "hello2"
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gJxAVwA4RgXhgbwFAwwCGAXLgYTAB5kCMANBQL6OEBGZ+lMAnmQEzNGTANx48UHqgCmMAOJI0AFSmzsAJWmgEAEwA80BAEswcejE3b9hk2ZjIwAazAgA7mAB8HsRNUwAakQANgDyAGZ6CijoMNJUUNJgOhhRyqoeWBSpMXEJSRiWILoGUMam5oXFNuUwJmHSCAFeMAD8ATBkYNIAbg0+kjIwALJEqJpQkYo58YnJ8lMqMhXSUBmYFDgwANoA0nK1YDCO0jwgYfPREAC6nNt7-gdHJ2cXaBC7clc3FiswTH8wABkuCY4jwYQcwCgRnAMAAtqNIrEZvlXqhFtJlqsABRwMhycxwsjY7pkQKhCJyDwASiwGXG1JIFBGYxWkSxGS4MAQK2QCEOITYACstFAAHRhJBwgCiYFKRmkEGxFEIgpFULFiXlitx1LFCNQyu4hGxW0c5m6V1pmAyWxVxvN9u4atFEqlsu1SqdxpdGq1xh13T1BuxpscRgtRitdO24cJJKMxAw5PCkRpVu9hGp3ozWaTw1G43ZP1WeFBeFAkFgCWgWHho1xUwgFpjAAMABbSIJBEAAEhw3SYrezFfAEBAQWkYp7cGxNag2aAA)

Comment: Wow wow wow, it works. I have no idea how, so I will go spend my morning working out how!